# File::exists return false for existing file in email job queued

Tags: php, laravel, email, queue, jobs

I'm trying to send an email using the Laravel's queue, in this email, I'm showing the profile picture of an user if the file exist using this function:

```
public function getProfilePictureAttribute()
{
    $path = 'users/' . $this->id . '/picture.png';
    if (File::exists(public_path() . $path)) {
        return $path;
    } else {
        return $this->picture_default;
    }
}
```

I use the same function on the web and it's working, but in the email, so via artisan and the table job, I always get the default picture. 
I can't figure this out.

Comment: bad c/c sorry, it's good on the code

Comment: did you try to dump public_path() . $path ? maybe missing a DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR between  ?

Comment: @Fky nope, there is everything...

Comment: maybe try with realpath(public_path() . $path)

Comment: realpath is the right way to do it ! thanks ! @Fky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved by :

```
public function getProfilePictureAttribute()
{
    $path = 'users/' . $this->id . '/picture.png';
    if (File::exists(realpath(public_path() . $path))) {
        return $path;
    } else {
        return $this->picture_default;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think your file path problem, but need to use Absolute path as like

```
$absulate_path = 'your absulate path';
// E:/xampp/htdocs/test_projuect      
$path = 'users/' . $this->id . '/picture.png';
 if (file_exists($absulate_path.'/'.$path)) {
   /* do your code
 } else {
       echo "file not exit";
 }
```

i think this will help you